# PHP json_decode not working on Object GET Variables

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, jsonp

I have an angular code using jsonp. In my params I have an object variable 'o_params'

javascript

```
$http({
            method: 'JSONP', 
            url: "site_url/create-order-app",
            params: {
                'callback'              : 'JSON_CALLBACK',
                'avoidCache'            : Date.now(),
                'o_params'              : {"test":"test"} //properly formatted object
            }
    })
```

in PHP
json_decode($_GET['o_params']) is producing null. When I check my o_params inside php, it seems that my object is now not properly formatted. Is it because of the GET and not POST?

How can I decode my o_params properly in php?

Comment: my o_params
{"s_timeStamp":"03/21/2016","s_cellphoneNumber":"011127559558", ...     


became like this when it arrived at my php
\"s_timeStamp\":\"03/21/2016\",\"s_cellphoneNumber\":\"011127559558\", ...

Comment: I found the culprit. Its because of the Wordpress. I can parse my params properly on normal php. But when using a php template file on Wordpress, it somewhat rewrites the GET variable before rendering... If only Wordpress does not do this...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this on your php file, and get your parameters:

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
```